# Runtime error 1004, method range of object _worksheet failed. Defining ranges in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, worksheet, named-ranges

I am defining some column ranges in VBA so that I can easily use the name of a range later instead of defining every time.
There are multiple worksheets in my workbook, which is why I'm defining the worksheet.
I get "Runtime error 1004: method range of object _worksheet failed, and debug highlights this line:

`Set PlateIDRng = Master.Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown))`

This is the whole code:

```
Sub defineRanges()

Dim WB As Workbook
Dim Master As Worksheet

Set WB = ThisWorkbook
Set Master = Worksheets("All_Plates_Mastersheet")

Dim PlateIDRng As Range
Dim ClientRng As Range
Dim ProjIDRng As Range
Dim PriorityRng As Range
Dim LimsStepRng As Range
Dim NumSamplesRng As Range
Dim LenNumRng As Range
Dim PhysLocRng As Range
Dim DateRecRng As Range

Set PlateIDRng = Master.Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown))
Set ClientRng = Master.Range("B2", Range("B2").End(xlDown))
Set ProjIDRng = Master.Range("C2", Range("C2").End(xlDown))
Set PriorityRng = Master.Range("D2", Range("D2").End(xlDown))
Set LimsStepRng = Master.Range("E2", Range("E2").End(xlDown))
Set NumSamplesRng = Master.Range("F2", Range("F2").End(xlDown))
Set LenNumRng = Master.Range("G2", Range("G2").End(xlDown))
Set PhysLocRng = Master.Range("H2", Range("H2").End(xlDown))
Set DateRecRng = Master.Range("I2", Range("I2").End(xlDown))

End Sub
```

I have tried structuring the 'last row' a few different ways but get the same error.

Comment: `Set PlateIDRng = Master.Range("A2", Master.Range("A2").End(xlDown))`

Comment: ... i.e. you need to *qualify* your ranges. Similarly, you also need to *qualify* your worksheet: `Set Master = WB.Worksheets("All_Plates_Mastersheet")`.

Comment: If you have a table of data rows (rather than a bunch of independent columns of values) then you only need to find the "last row" *once*, ideally using a column which is always populated with a value.

Answer (score 0):

The error should only come up if you are running the code while `Master` is not the active sheet. The reason is that `Range("A2").End(xlDown)` is not qualified with a sheet, so it references the range on whatever sheet you have active. If you activate `Master` before that block of code, it should work. But the correct structure would be

```
Set PlateIDRng = Range(Master.Range("A2"), Master.Range("A2").End(xlDown))
```

And the neater format would be (note the `.` in front of `.Range`)

```
With Master
    Set PlateIDRng = .Range(.Range("A2"), .Range("A2").End(xlDown))
End With
```

Comment: Thank you @peter this worked! I used "with master" and defined Master with WB. in the beginning

Comment: @TimWilliams I do take your word for it, although I can't think of any case where the outer `.Range(...)` makes a difference as long as the inner `(.Range, .Range)` are qualified... Still, have updated my answer with your suggestion.

Comment: It's pretty common to see usage something like `Range("A2", Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp))` here - that's what I was thinking of, but that's outside of your "as long as the inner... are qualified"